# Can apache nifi detect database table record change and how?

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi

I'm really new to apache-nifi, I'm not sure this can be achieved in the nifi processor or not?

Say I have a table called "USArrests":

**Before update**

The first record of "Murder" is 15.5.

[image]

**After update**

The first record of "Murder" changed to 13.2.

[image]

How can this change be detected by setting the processor if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

Remove `binlog_do_db` from my.cnf.

Not able to explain why. Will update answer when I know (if someone does, please explain).